# How to switch off re-POST request in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http

I'm working with a lot of POST-backs using AJAX, but whenever I test my web-app I constantly have to confirm POST http data to be resent.

Is there a way to stop Chrome from asking me to confirm POST requests (in particular for single sites, but perhaps for all sites)?

Appreciate the help.